# How to change tab control tab item's header color [MahApps.Metro]

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a `MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl` from MahApps Metro. I want to change the header's foregorund color from blue (defined by the template) to white.

This is what I have got:

```
<Grid x:Name="Body" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0,20,0">
    <controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
        <controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
            <controls:MetroTabItem Header="Server"/>
        </controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
    </controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
</Grid>
```

I want to let the `Server` Header to appear in white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colors are set in the triggers towards the end of the [TabItem template](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.TabControl.xaml).

Once you got the Keys you can overwrite the resource bindings

```
<Grid x:Name="Body" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0,20,0">
    <Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
        <Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush" Color="Orange"/>
        </Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl.Resources>
        <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="Server"/>
    </Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
</Grid>
```